# PHP convert Array to XML

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I have an array like so:

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [Project] => Array
                (
                    [ExternalProjectID] => 53
                    [ProjectName] => Doon Creek
                    [Location] => Array
                        (
                            [Address] => 123 Fake Street
                            [City] => Toronto
                            [Province] => ON
                            [Latitude] => 43.0000
                            [Longitude] =>  -80.0000
                        )

                    [Website] => http://www.website.com/our-communities.php?newcommunity=53
                    [ContactInformation] => Array
                        (
                            [ContactPhone] => 555-5555
                            [ContactEmail] => email@email.com
                            [SalesOfficeAddress] => 123 Fake Street
                            [SalesOfficeCity] => Toronto
                            [SalesOfficeProvince] => ON
                        )

                )

        )
```

Now I am trying to covert this to XML exactly how this looks in the array, like Project should be a node with everything inside, Location should also be a node with everything inside the Location array inside that node, along with ContactInformation.

This is what I have:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement();

$node = $xml->addChild('Projects');

array_to_xml($newArray, $node);

echo $xml->asXML();
die();

function array_to_xml($array, &$xml) {
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        if(is_array($value)) {
            if(!is_numeric($key)){
                $subnode = $xml->addChild("$key");
                array_to_xml($value, $xml);
            } else {
                array_to_xml($value, $xml);
            }
        } else {
            $xml->addChild("$key","$value");
        }
    }
}
```

but Project, Location and ContactInformation return as  like so:

```
<Projects>
      <Project />
      <ExternalProjectID>53</ExternalProjectID>
      <ProjectName>Doon Creek</ProjectName>
      <Location />
      <Address>123 Fake St.</Address>
      <City>Toronto</City>
      <Province>ON</Province>
      <Latitude>43.0000</Latitude>
      <Longitude>-80.000</Longitude>
      <Website>http://www.website.com/our-communities.php?newcommunity=53</Website>
      <ContactInformation />
      <ContactPhone>555-5555</ContactPhone>
      <ContactEmail>email@email.com</ContactEmail>
      <SalesOfficeAddress>123 Fake Street</SalesOfficeAddress>
      <SalesOfficeCity>Toronto</SalesOfficeCity>
      <SalesOfficeProvince>ON</SalesOfficeProvince>
      <Project />
</Projects>
```

My question is how do I fix my XML Output?

Comment: Have you referred [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397036/how-to-convert-array-to-simplexml)?

Comment: The second answer worked for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Almost had it! You simply had to pass the `$subnode`, not `$xml` into the recursive call of function:

```
// XML BUILD RECURSIVE FUNCTION
function array_to_xml($array, &$xml) {        
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {               
        if(is_array($value)) {            
            if(!is_numeric($key)){
                $subnode = $xml->addChild($key);
                array_to_xml($value, $subnode);
            } else {
                array_to_xml($value, $subnode);
            }
        } else {
            $xml->addChild($key, $value);
        }
    }        
}

// EXAMPLE ARRAY
$newArray = array(
                 "Project" =>
                  array("ExternalProjectID" => 53,
                        "ProjectName" => "Doon Creek",
                        "Location" => 
                         array ("Address" => "123 Fake Street",
                                "City" => "Toronto",
                                "Province" => "ON",
                                "Latitude" => 43.0000,
                                "Longitude" => -80.0000),
                        "Website" => 
                        "http://www.website.com/our-communities.php?newcommunity=53",
                        "ContactInformation" => 
                         array("ContactPhone" => "555-5555",
                               "ContactEmail" => "email@email.com",
                               "SalesOfficeAddress" => "123 Fake Street",
                               "SalesOfficeCity" => "Toronto",
                               "SalesOfficeProvince" => "ON")
                       )
                );

// CREATING XML OBJECT
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<Projects/>'); 
array_to_xml($newArray, $xml);

// TO PRETTY PRINT OUTPUT
$domxml = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$domxml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$domxml->formatOutput = true;
$domxml->loadXML($xml->asXML());

echo $domxml->saveXML();
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Projects>
  <Project>
    <ExternalProjectID>53</ExternalProjectID>
    <ProjectName>Doon Creek</ProjectName>
    <Location>
      <Address>123 Fake Street</Address>
      <City>Toronto</City>
      <Province>ON</Province>
      <Latitude>43</Latitude>
      <Longitude>-80</Longitude>
    </Location>
    <Website>http://www.website.com/our-communities.php?newcommunity=53</Website>
    <ContactInformation>
      <ContactPhone>555-5555</ContactPhone>
      <ContactEmail>email@email.com</ContactEmail>
      <SalesOfficeAddress>123 Fake Street</SalesOfficeAddress>
      <SalesOfficeCity>Toronto</SalesOfficeCity>
      <SalesOfficeProvince>ON</SalesOfficeProvince>
    </ContactInformation>
  </Project>
</Projects>
```

Comment: It throws the undefined variable in else condition `$subnode`. Can you check which variable should be there on non numeric $key?

Comment: @JigneshBhavani, if you are trying to implement this solution on a different XML than OP's sample, please ask a *new* question.

Answer (score 1):

In general, it is verified the key is numeric, but the correct one is if the first one is numeric, if there is something empty "_" is added

```
<?php
$file = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ZiTAL/flickr-php-cli/master/composer.json';
$file = file_get_contents($file);
$array = json_decode($file, true);

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$root = $dom->createElement('root');
$dom->appendChild($root);

array2xml($array, $root, $dom);

echo $dom->saveXML();

function array2xml($array, $node, &$dom)
{
    foreach($array as $key => $value)
    {
        if(preg_match("/^[0-9]/", $key))
            $key = "node-{$key}";
        $key = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9_\-]+/i", '', $key);

        if($key==='')
            $key = '_';

        $a = $dom->createElement($key);
        $node->appendChild($a);

        if(!is_array($value))
            $a->appendChild($dom->createTextNode($value));
        else
            array2xml($value, $a, $dom);
    }
}
```

input:

```
{
    "name": "thefox/flickr-cli",
    "description": "Upload and download Flickr photos, photo sets, directories via shell.",
    "license": "GPL-3.0",
    "type": "project",
    "keywords": [
        "Flickr",
        "Upload",
        "Download",
        "Photo",
        "CLI"
    ],
    "homepage": "https://github.com/TheFox/flickr-cli",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Christian Mayer",
            "email": "christian@fox21.at",
            "homepage": "https://fox21.at"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.0",
        "rezzza/flickr": "^1.1",
        "symfony/yaml": "^2.3",
        "symfony/console": "^3.1",
        "symfony/filesystem": "^3.1",
        "symfony/finder": "^3.1",
        "monolog/monolog": "^1.21",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^3.8",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "^0.2",
        "rych/bytesize": "^1.0",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.5"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpstan/phpstan": "^0.7",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "^3.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "": "src"
        }
    },
    "bin": [
        "bin/flickr-cli"
    ]
}
```

output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <name>thefox/flickr-cli</name>
  <description>Upload and download Flickr photos, photo sets, directories via shell.</description>
  <license>GPL-3.0</license>
  <type>project</type>
  <keywords>
    <node-0>Flickr</node-0>
    <node-1>Upload</node-1>
    <node-2>Download</node-2>
    <node-3>Photo</node-3>
    <node-4>CLI</node-4>
  </keywords>
  <homepage>https://github.com/TheFox/flickr-cli</homepage>
  <authors>
    <node-0>
      <name>Christian Mayer</name>
      <email>christian@fox21.at</email>
      <homepage>https://fox21.at</homepage>
    </node-0>
  </authors>
  <require>
    <php>^7.0</php>
    <rezzzaflickr>^1.1</rezzzaflickr>
    <symfonyyaml>^2.3</symfonyyaml>
    <symfonyconsole>^3.1</symfonyconsole>
    <symfonyfilesystem>^3.1</symfonyfilesystem>
    <symfonyfinder>^3.1</symfonyfinder>
    <monologmonolog>^1.21</monologmonolog>
    <guzzlehttpguzzle>^3.8</guzzlehttpguzzle>
    <lusitanianoauth>^0.2</lusitanianoauth>
    <rychbytesize>^1.0</rychbytesize>
    <doctrinedbal>^2.5</doctrinedbal>
  </require>
  <require-dev>
    <phpstanphpstan>^0.7</phpstanphpstan>
    <squizlabsphp_codesniffer>^3.0</squizlabsphp_codesniffer>
  </require-dev>
  <autoload>
    <psr-4>
      <_>src</_>
    </psr-4>
  </autoload>
  <bin>
    <node-0>bin/flickr-cli</node-0>
  </bin>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

[REFER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397036/how-to-convert-array-to-simplexml)

```
    <?php
    // function defination to convert array to xml
    function array_to_xml( $data, &$xml_data ) {
        foreach( $data as $key => $value ) {
            if( is_array($value) ) {
                if( is_numeric($key) ){
                    $key = 'item'.$key; //dealing with <0/>..<n/> issues
                }
                $subnode = $xml_data->addChild($key);
                array_to_xml($value, $subnode);
            } else {
                $xml_data->addChild("$key",htmlspecialchars("$value"));
            }
         }
    }

    // initializing or creating array
    $data = array('total_stud' => 500);

    // creating object of SimpleXMLElement
    $xml_data = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0"?><data></data>');

    // function call to convert array to xml
    array_to_xml($data,$xml_data);

    //saving generated xml file; 
    $result = $xml_data->asXML('/file/path/name.xml');

    ?>
```

[Documentation on SimpleXMLElement::asXML used in this snippet](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php)